# sql server database connect to c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, localdb, sql-server-2014

I have a user database on a local server and everything seems to work fine. The only problem is I can't connect from my C++ console application. The connect string in the code is correct but I think I am using the parameter incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle){
SQLCHAR sqlstate[1024];
SQLCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
    cout << "Message: " << message << "nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}

int main(){

    SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
//  SQLRETURN retcode;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
    goto FINISHED;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
    goto FINISHED;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
    goto FINISHED;

    SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;        Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;DATABASE=SampleDatabase1;",
    SQL_NTS,
    retconstring,
    1024,
    NULL,
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)){
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
    show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
    case SQL_ERROR:
    show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    goto FINISHED;
default:
    break;

    //Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
}

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
    goto FINISHED;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT * FROM User", SQL_NTS)){
    show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
    goto FINISHED;
   }
    else{
        char username[64];
        char password[64];
        int id;
    while (SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle) == SQL_SUCCESS){
        SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
        SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, username, 64, NULL);
        SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, password, 64, NULL);
        cout << id << " " << username << " " << password << endl;
    }
}

FINISHED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Also noticed you're setting Initial Catalog and Database parameters -- those are the same parameter AFAIK, so you should probably just use one.

Comment: 1. There isn't an error. It just runs and freezes.
2. Where am I setting those parameters incorrectly? Can you show me the correct usage?

Comment: I was referring to your connection string